# Which parts of a RSA private key is secret?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa, private-key

This is a RSA private key :

```
<BitStrength>4944</BitStrength>
<RSAKeyValue>
    <Modulus>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</Modulus>
    <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
    <P>8RUZbaB91ve478Jam2QjOWooTrvtaOzoe6hygPA8E6GlEqwryGg2180lUUoM+RdFTgmKvxaLyV7Xg4RZHD0vWYmE4VT/ChulT52qn8IPgIV1O+F67EVh4ovVCx/vXEiDCLpzWRgyMr8VazsM71xmLi8N5+3esFNcdoFk7a+7odVC5xIAK8N/BiXu+PVYeai4begJTvXtK1bFFr7TQCmC6JUp84/dFCoNIyMHjVFYuz2Td8D3quxjPRaj+fnjYtce92JD0v5rkfmYTSFt2EbZKkdMJpS7MeDmFErOUDSYVOdu7CbmlVbXcD6QbSC2RbX/fbyTWwyAti3JSJ+WzUbrnp9olXEcldMt7Z8okT2Y9apxmKNYibq0XN+JPhdBlk1EffhRiCGHfFAsNME85dvRI0naJMxD</P>
    <Q>ynJ6nUraqvWP178eFFbrY//r274r59ckV/4/TFd/vlxPjLR4XpRgM16o/rrIyjDqko5MCm4f0LYZoNfe/6/Xz1WsbfuFCcp+SdFrVFDjE4rzszys25/fum4TcsSbmsQflNY108QD0Mf+6xBsuVlWh8WWXKim0aplVF6tEiz3bMEWWjTM5Wuv65hEO9V6q+BNJ+j3VqZdVBPKKqnyxxK84zFXec8JqGqYo2qxFEahunagv0hm5sCLerv3GcBAy719q43eecwHfIEgNuAFoMLr4R/IFMLPy31CQHMalFRazfu4CZoIwDkDVZHfACHDoLR+91LbMG/UZhRnv0YZ9+fFajINxTPkgIvLwaf624yZ2DOF8h+Aor5evHZ00/iD6AP0kogjd0JlXTvVVL2R8VeGowfkHnEl</Q>
    <DP>oTHmarKg8Zd5hHaDdtsh4kXk5aAqQboGSIh851G6GbY/VZjhPYLRCMIWbaABxJuWr3MZ3mMI3IAZwcpAeu0+N7QHsVLPpMaPZgiaCXAMRXb2yC8frdNGe9/bdzDHLwEc/D0O20eeaOfzPluhbnptp/u2ZJlcCLH0ZRhnj7Ws06xwq2gRzTFOQaIjgzspCU+S4YoAj1dIWW4PIgI95ezbpv/1qPFMdSsY1aGabxcxKSEm9S+Fajfcsv/sbDx1maUVA3wktXOAIX6uIwRzGeVlVyuM808HS3aA4JiUEnTYVgzY0fXAv6HtMxPiJdV1im8CgeQQ8xQNC8LZj0GF54PAD7Oujh2va05kqzl8OoDhQYHRqqmtjYnVBzQ/49BQ/lpzrXbXrRoeKTTCGhQKz/aGg/3hajFZ</DP>
    <DQ>TOlFD/DaNkzoguyGvu9uqiUWM/uBrqiblBpxbc1oKKflSO1fNX9lNN7nkS7hDX+b/mW1GdlQmPg1sFeSzsy9TnWb9oSxvFCDvgOjpPq96jTF9Pg+K4oHc0pSdS2geCG+Zcsj0/oKAQ2aGS+6PohkSVyVjUo9ZjY4HN+DHP6cWWLZ3RdmKFrLENReR+UIn7etWFY3cWHu3vxNt/us0liaDi42r34qiyNELgFgmPVkh/R9iW42OcA4vT4f2Fajx0OMNNrHBLqwtWpRFMfzG2oyNureFpUUYJiLzPRtyqBphwv0lSFB5dVDIQU0FVa+fZVVDx0ZTMOPi+CAsbguMXKKG5g8hwj57KQvmrj4ouQ9plecsamqMynjz/Go3MbzRfgKuIikALDm1Y7fszv58BhyfAmJbs9J</DQ>
    <InverseQ>3awPjKSwbmVsn+Ip7nwwSRgJHJhHBqr/KmT7NBv9cOAFXEaz9v7VmhSLU3GZcfHi9J0gTa/2POCd5X3IT5bEtf42jDgfP39vGDqc8liWOZG2Ha7Y/TteIO9REAIy7tTPdWWG0TyBVQah4eC0A9KS9GDR1cLL0wdky38ppNwZT3V1kzgBoow1Agea44rM+tgUIZtrPxtHHBNFgX2Mkbn3CZKg1Qpe98GjIGEkZhwMM3RfYo0uW732t908gDNBaMY5S5+ixr3XZfph9wJZiq1JUwMhMPa8gGTLiRNm6rDlNimgaAv3iBnGCZhSdX11bbj5qQrM17wDqyOyk44ywt1T9SW9K6Tode57pUoxVB9XkOLHCnx6of371xx5bhZ4l9NIbdLldfj1CI4bSOMqN/r7UZ96upoJ</InverseQ>
    <D>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</D>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

It contains couple of elements (**Modules**, **Exponent**, **P**, **E**, **DP**, **DQ**, **InverseQ**, **D**)

I read somewhere that the main element of a RSA private key is **D**.

But I want to know which parts of these elements should be secret and which parts can be  publicly shared ? (Means there's no security problem if it be shared)

Thanks

Comment: Private keys, as name suggests, imho are intended to remain private.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about cryptography and is better asked on http://crypto.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From Wikipedia:
The public key consists of the modulus n and the public (or encryption) exponent e. The private key consists of the modulus n and the private (or decryption) exponent d, which must be kept secret. p, q, and φ(n) must also be kept secret because they can be used to calculate d.

This means that that you are correct. D is the most important part, but because 'd' can be found from other information (p,DP,DQ, InverseQ) they too should also be kept secret. The modulus and exponent form the public key.

source: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28cryptosystem%29)

Comment: I would also keep the key size secret, because 4944 is a very strange value for an RSA key :) It can still be divided by 8 I guess.

Comment: The RSA key size is never secret. It is the size of the public key modulus n. Yes that is a strange keysize. Maybe it wasgenerated as an experiment?